# How will I change the background of layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I am learning android and its difficult to sperate UI and logic in android as it recommends xml way. I am trying to learn it . I need help in changing background

I have two image in my layout. One is HUD will be at the left and other will be bg 
There are many bg's but right now I have just put one .I need help how to change this bg's as user will click on some button.

In my main1.xml - There are 8 buttons as user will click on button respective to that bg has to come in the main2.xml

Here is the code for main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Horizontal Layout for HUD and Level Screen -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- Vertical Layout for the HUD which includes Object list,Timer, Pause and Menu Button -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/hud"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Relative Layout for the Level Screen -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/GamePlayScreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" >                 
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This works for one bg how to keep same layout main2.xml and keep on changin bg w.r.t to button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you inflate your view do this:

myView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

d being your drawable.

Answer (score 1):

create xml like this i did for 4 buttons add 4 more for ur requirement

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linear">

    <Button<
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity for the above xml in activity we can change the backgrounds by using java code

```
  package com.capo.searchrestaurant.activities;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       LinearLayout l;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
             l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
             Button btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
             Button btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
             Button btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
             Button btn4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
             btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
             btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
             btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
             btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
         //.......
        }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId())
      {
      case R.id.button1:
          l.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
          break;
      case R.id.button2:
          l.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.images));
          break;
      case R.id.button3:
          l.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
          break;
      case R.id.button4:
          l.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.images));
          break;
       //....for remaining buttons
      }

     }
    }
```

Comment: okk which activity layout u wuld like to change?? give me clear clarification

Comment: In my above code i.e. in my main2.xml Relative layout drawable which is bg that has to be changed . Here is the flow .. my main1.xml has buttons like level1,level2 etc...depending on the selection I have to put bg in Relative layout of main2.xml whose id is android:background="@drawable/bg

Answer (score 0):

you could try
    view.setBackgroundResource(int)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

Not used it myself so I dont know whether it works